# f7-Radio Buttons not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, html-framework-7

When I click through all 3 sections of radio buttons, they randomly reset when clicking through them. For example: if I choose an option from section one of the radio buttons, then go to the section 2 or 3 and select an option; all previous selected sections are cleared. why is this happening? How can I fix this? below is a code snippet of how I have the radio buttons implemented

```html
<f7-list-item media-list :value="event.section1" >
        <f7-label>Section 1 </f7-label>    
        <f7-radio class="Yes" name="radio1" value="Yes" title="Yes" @change="event.section1 = $event.target.value">Yes</f7-radio>
        <f7-radio class="No" name="radio1" value="No" title="No" @change="event.section1 = $event.target.value">No</f7-radio>
</f7-list-item>
<f7-list-item media-list :value="event.section2" >
        <f7-label>Section 2 </f7-label>    
        <f7-radio class="Mild" name="radio2" value="Mild" title="Mild" @change="event.section2= $event.target.value">Mild</f7-radio>
        <f7-radio class="Moderate" name="radio2" value="Moderate" title="Moderate" @change="event.section2= $event.target.value">Moderate</f7-radio>
        <f7-radio class="Severe" name="radio2" value="Severe" title="Severe" @change="event.section2= $event.target.value">Severe</f7-radio>
</f7-list-item>
<f7-list-item media-list :value="event.section3" >
        <f7-label>Section 3 </f7-label>      
        <f7-radio class="Mild" name="radio3" value="Mild" title="Mild" @change="event.section3 = $event.target.value">Mild</f7-radio>
        <f7-radio class="Moderate" name="radio3" value="Moderate" title="Moderate" @change="event.section3 = $event.target.value">Moderate</f7-radio>
        <f7-radio class="Severe" name="radio3" value="Severe" title="Severe" @change="event.section3 = $event.target.value">Severe</f7-radio>
</f7-list-item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you construct a list of radio buttons with F7 & vue, use `f7-list` and `f7-list-item` instead.

Example for group :

```
   <f7-block-title>Section 1</f7-block-title>
    <f7-list>
      <f7-list-item radio value="Yes" name="radio1" checked title="...."></f7-list-item>
      <f7-list-item radio value="No" name="radio1" title="...."></f7-list-item>
    </f7-list>
```

**UPDATE**

if you want style with circle radio, you can use something like this (without `f7-list-item` :

```
<f7-block-title>Section 1</f7-block-title>
<f7-block>
    <f7-radio value="Yes" name="radio1"></f7-radio>
    <f7-radio value="No" name="radio1"></f7-radio>
</f7-block>
```

[Check the docs](http://framework7.io/vue/radio.html#examples) for more infos

Comment: Doing it this way, works better. however I dont get the circular radio buttons anymore. it displays the options "Yes" and "No" as their own separate row.

Comment: Ok, so you can use inline radio instead, check my update in the answer !